# Number of subgroups of order p

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and consider the group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$. How many subgroups of order $p$ does it have? Given any two subgroups $B_1, B_2 $ of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ of order $p$, is there an automorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(B_1) =B_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The subgroups of order $p$ are generated by $(1,pk)$ for $k=0,..,p-1$ and $(0,p)$. That gives $p+1$ distinct subgroups.

Now, find two such subgroups, $B_1$ and $B_2$ such that $G/B_1\not\cong G/B_2$ (where $G$ is your product group.) That would answer your second question in the negative.